# What's the difference between two potential (כוחניים) maters the Yuly and the second

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, creation, ramban, abarbanel

I read in the [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org/Abarbanel_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.1.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) on Bereishit 1:1,quoting the Ramban, that on the first day Hashem created two types of primordial matter:

> הראשון לבד שני חמרים מבלי צורה **כוחניים** בטבעם כענין ההיולי הראשון שזכרו הפלוסופים ושמאחד מהם עשה אחר כך כל הדברים העליונים ומהאחר עשה כל הדברים התחתונים ושעל **שני החמרים הכוחניים** ההם אמר בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ שהם אשר נבראו בתחילה

I can't find this Ramban anywhere, but I did find one on the heyulie. What's the difference?

It's not in any of my dictionaries and Google directed me back to the Abarbanel.

Comment: Voted to close - unclear what you're asking. Please try to provide sources.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Abarbanel_on_Torah,_Genesis.1.1 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/abarbanel-bereshit/abarbanel-bereshit0001.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjdq_Pt6NDhAhVEFzQIHcrbDboQFjANegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2dCFkToGJoVPieqnBvm2EJ https://books.google.com/books?id=224tAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=ההיולי+כחניים&source=bl&ots=tFUKGafXSh&sig=ACfU3U1CkaZ65N016tzQ1GAZCT0ef03Srw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT05CR6dDhAhVZCTQIHTw9Bo8Q6AEwC3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=ההיולי%20כחניים&f=false and malbim: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Malbim/Bereshit/1.4#m7e0n6

Comment: The abarbanel is explaining creation. He says that there were two primordial types of matter. I know what heyulie is but not חניים. What is this other substance?

Comment: Sorry I could only spot כחניים from כוח. Can you provide the exact sentence.

Comment: אמנם הרמב"ן קבל שבא הכתוב לספר סוד הבריאה וכתב שברא הקב"ה מהאין המוחלט ביום הראשון לבד שני חמרים מבלי צורה כחניי' בטבעם כענין ההיולי הראשון שזכרו הפלוסופים ושמאחד מהם עשה אחר כך כל הדברים העליונים ומהאחר עשה כל הדברים התחתונים ושעל שני החמרים הכחניים ההם אמר בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ שהם אשר נבראו בתחלה.

Comment: THat's כחניים - Kochani from Koach. Otherwise you can't say Hakochaniim.

Comment: Berko is right כוחניים הטובים is potentially by their nature

Comment: Then why does he say shnei chamarim? What's the other chomer ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe Abarbanel is referring to this line of [Ramban on Bereishit 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.1.1.3?lang=bi):

> ודע, כי השמים וכל אשר בהם – חומר אחד, והארץ וכל אשר בה – חומר אחד. והקב"ה ברא אלו שניהם מאין, ושניהם לבדם נבראים, והכל נעשים מהם. והחומר הזה, שקראו היולי, נקרא בלשון הקדש "תֹּהוּ"‏
>
> And know that the heavens and all that is in them are one material, and the earth and all that is within it is [another] material; and the Holy One, blessed be He, created both of them from nothing - and the two of them alone were created, and everything was made from them. And this material that they called hyle is called tohu (chaos) in the Holy Tongue.

That is G-d created two kinds of primordial *hyle*, one with which He formed the heavens, and one the earth.

(The translation of your quote from Abarbanel means that G-d created two kinds of formless material, potential in their nature, similar to the primordial *hyle* of which the philosophers speak. The word כחניים means potential (as noted by Al Berko and kouty in comments to the OP).)